# Using a state used in a header and updating its content based on Route with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to update a header based on text from a route. But cant seem to get the header to update.
I am using `useState()` hooks. Ive also used `useEffect()` hooks but the header doesnt seem to update. So header should say 'new header' not 'default header'. I am using 'react-router-dom' for my router.

`app.js` is :

```
function App() {
  const [header, setHeader] = useState('default header')
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navigation />
        <Header heading={header} />
        <main>
          <Route exact path='/case-study' render={routeProps => (
            <Child {...routeProps} setHeader={() => setHeader} />
          )} />
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My Child route is:

```
const CaseStudy = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        props.setHeader('new header')
    })
    return(
        <h1>test</h1>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can try to change app.js like this**

```
<Child {...routeProps} setHeader={(params) => setHeader(params)} />
```

Comment: could you please explain how this works and what each part is doing to keep the headers state up to date?

Because I was under the impression there was no child--> parent communication. I really need to understand this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```js
 <Child {...routeProps} setHeader={setHeader} />
```

Comment: could you please explain how this works and what each part is doing to keep the headers state up to date?

Because I was under the impression there was no child--> parent communication. I really need to understand this.

Thank you.